# Network diagram in PlantUML not working as expected?

Tags: plantuml

I am trying to create a network diagram for my office using PlantUML.  I am stuck very early on.  I am beginning at the edge of our network and working downwards.  I would like to use the sprites as much as possible.

I have

```
@startuml
!include <office/Servers/application_server>
!include <office/Devices/router>

nwdiag {
  internet [shape = cloud];
  router [description="<$router>\nRouter"];
  internet -- router;
  
}
@enduml
```

which shows
[image]
which is not using the sprite I asked for.  If I rename the router in the connection like so -

```
@startuml
!include <office/Servers/application_server>
!include <office/Devices/router>

nwdiag {
  internet [shape = cloud];
  router [description="<$router>\nRouter"];
  internet -- router2;
  
}
@enduml
```

I do see my sprite though obviously it's not in the right place.

[image]

I do not see what I am doing wrong.  How I can I connect the internet to the object called router which has the sprite attached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those quirky things about ordering in PlantUML (not very logical). But I put the link line before the sprite line, and it works.

```
@startuml
!include <office/Servers/application_server>
!include <office/Devices/router>

nwdiag {
  internet [shape = cloud];
  internet -- router;
  router [description="<$router>\nRouter"];
  
}
@enduml
```

[image]